# Editing a string with lots of escape characters

Tags: text-editing

Let's say I'm editing my config file and there is a very long string like this:

```
(setq my-string "very\nlong\nstring [...] \"hello world\"")
```

How do edit the string without the escape characters (and maybe in a different mode) and than save the result back in the config file with the escape characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the package [string-edit](https://github.com/magnars/string-edit.el) for that purpose.

Essentially, it does exactly what you want: simply call `string-edit-at-point` to edit the string at point, then `C-c C-c` to return to the original buffer.

The documentation on github includes a [demonstration](https://asciinema.org/a/3040) (if the link appears to be dead, please see the github page directly).

Comment: Your demonstration link goes to a parked domain.

Comment: Apparently the link on the github page was changed, I updated the answer.